# Too long fetch doments from collention in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

For example, I have inserted 10K documents in collection:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 100; ++$j) {
        $collection->insert(array('i' => $i, 'j' => $j));
    }
}
```

I have created Indexes:

```
pkrs:PRIMARY> db.testTest.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "parts.testTest",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "i" : 1,
                        "j" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "parts.testTest",
                "name" : "i_1_j_1"
        }
]
```

Then I want to fetch 600 documents with 'OR' condition:

```
for ($i = 5; $i < 12; ++$i) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 100; ++$j) {
        $orArr[] = array('i'=>$i, 'j' => $j);
    }
}
$cursor = $collection->find(array('$or' => $orArr));
$cursor->batchSize(1000);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
   // code
}
```

And first document fetches about 1.5 second! :(
How can I improve performance?

Comment: That is a little subjective to possible hardware issues. Can you post your "explain" output? But I think I already see the result. Post it in you question anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the correct database with the indexes? I can reproduce your > 1second query time when I don't have indexes on it (actually takes my laptop 2.2seconds) - but when I added the index in your example ($collection->createIndex(array("i" => 1, "j" => 1));) it takes under 0.06

Comment: ...Although I am worried that you will be adding more $or to your query.. its not very good practice to have so many $or's. Maybe you should create another SO question with your schema and current query practices and ask for improvements suggestions :)